# AStudio issue #66894

Tags: android-studio

In the middle of development it threw an error at me complaining about gradle plugin being too old (was  2.0.0-alpha3, changed to 2.0.0-alpha5 and worked. Hurrah!). Then it complained about `distributionUrl` pointing to an also outdated piece of software. I have Overcome that as well. Now google nailed me with

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoDebugLoader'.
> Exception while loading build-info.xml : null
```

Invalidate + restart didnt do the trick. What next ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I also meet this error today.
You can try to clean project and rebuild project when you upgrade the version of Gradle or any other plugins.
I found this is helpful.

Comment: I also have the error, can you explain with more details how to solve it please ?

Comment: Just go at the AndroidStudio toolbar to Build > Clean Project and then Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: Yes, Clean and Build your project again. This solution worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I went to Build > Build types, switched back and forth between types, then done a clean and build (not rebuild). Worked. Lol

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned project, and after that updated android studio to last version at preview channel. Thats worked for me